# Computer and Wii U sharing a Y Cable for power?

Tags: hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive, power-supply

So, currently I own a Western Digital Hard Drive (500 GB), P/N is WDBKXH5000ABK.  I use this for data storage on my Wii U, and as a result, it requires a Y-Cable to function properly (as do most Hard Drives on the Wii U).

However, unfortunately the Wii U only has 2 USB Ports.  While this isn't a issue normally, if I need one of those two USB Ports for another device or item, I'm left without any way to plug in the orange power-only cable.

My question is, could I run a USB extension cable from the orange power-only cable into my PC's USB ports, and have my PC provide the extra power, while having the data cable still in the Wii U?  Would this risk any harm to the Wii U, PC, or Hard Drive?

Answer (score 2):

There's no guarantee that it will not cause a problem. The +5 from the Wii and the PC are likely not exactly at the same voltage. But your Y-cable will connect their grounds together, so any voltage difference between the +5's will result in current flow between the two.

This won't necessarily cause a problem but nobody can guarantee that it won't.

Can the Wii tolerate a USB hub? Try using a powered USB hub, and plug both of the plugs of the Y cable into two ports on the hub.

Comment: That is the only safe way of doing this. The powered hub and its powersupply are designed to be safe for this usage. Cross-connecting between 2 USB controllers (WII and PC) is outside of USB specifications and could cause damage to HD, WII or PC. (Or all of them if you are really unlucky.)

Comment: So just to make sure, I plug a USB hub into USB1 on the Wii U, with the hub having it's own dedicated power supply, and put both cables of the Y Cable into the hub?   Not sure the Wii U will even permit a hub, but this does sound like a safer alternative worth trying.

Comment: You have described my answer correctly.